# KATA EXERCISE JS switch statement and callback functions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve this exercise where all outputs must be displayed on terminal.

Task

You'll still be given an input string to convert. However, this time, you'll also be given a casing style to work with. The following code block will describe all the casing styles to support. You may also receive an array of casing styles, and each of these should be applied.

Precedence of each of the casing styles are as follows, values higher in the list should be processed first:

camel, pascal, snake, kebab, title
vowel, consonant
upper, lower

Testing and outputs should be as follows:

```
makeCase("this is a string", "camel") === "thisIsAString";

makeCase("this is a string", "pascal") === "ThisIsAString";
makeCase("this is a string", "snake") === "this_is_a_string";
makeCase("this is a string", "kebab") === "this-is-a-string";
makeCase("this is a string", "title") === "This Is A String";
makeCase("this is a string", "vowel") === "thIs Is A strIng";
makeCase("this is a string", "consonant") === "THiS iS a STRiNG";
makeCase("this is a string", ["upper", "snake"]) ==="THIS_IS_A_STRING";
```

Here is the Code I have come up with so far. Apologies it is very long. I am learning javascript and am a noob.

```
      var makeCase = function(input, font)
      {
      var array = input.split(' ')

      var newarray = []
      var rez = []
      var tier = []
      font = font.toString()

      // **************************************CALLBACK FUNCTIONS FONT ********************************

            var camel = function()
            {
              for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
                    {
                      newarray.push(array[x].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+array[x].slice(1));
                    }

                    var b = newarray.join('');

                    var pieces = b.split("");

                    var lower = pieces[0].toLowerCase()

                    var result = pieces.splice(0,1,lower)

                    rez.push(pieces.join(""))
            }


              var pascal = function()
              {
                for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
                    {
                      newarray.push(array[x].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+array[x].slice(1));
                    }
                    var b = newarray.join('');

                    var pieces = b.split("");

                    var upper = pieces[0].toUpperCase()

                    var result = pieces.splice(0,1,upper)

                    rez.push(pieces.join(""))
              }

              var snake = function()
              {
                var array = input.split("")
                  for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
                        {
                          newarray.push(array[x]);
                          if (array[x] === ' ')
                          {
                            newarray.push("_")
                          }
                        }
                          var pieces = newarray.join(" ").replace(/\s/g,'')
                          rez.push(pieces)
              }

              var kebab = function()
              {
                var array = input.split("")
                  for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
                        {
                          newarray.push(array[x]);
                          if (array[x] === ' ')
                          {
                            newarray.push("-")
                          }
                        }
                          var pieces = newarray.join(" ").replace(/\s/g,'')
                          rez.push(pieces.join(""));
              }

             var title = function()
             {
                for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
                    {
                      newarray.push(array[x].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+array[x].slice(1));
                    }
                    var b = newarray.join(' ');

                    var pieces = b.split("");

                    var upper = pieces[0].toUpperCase()

                    var result = pieces.splice(0,1,upper).join("")

                    rez.push(pieces.join(""))
             }


             var vowel = function()
             {
              var array = input.split("")
                for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
                    {
                      if (array[x] === 'a' || array[x] === 'e' || array[x] === 'i' || array[x] === 'o' || array[x] === 'u')
                      {
                        newarray.push(array[x].charAt(0).toUpperCase(array[x]))
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        newarray.push(array[x])
                      }
                    }
                    var pieces = newarray.join(' ');
                    tier.push(pieces.join(""))
             }

              var consonant = function()
             {
              var array = input.split("")
                for(var x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
                    {
                      if (array[x] === 'a' || array[x] === 'e' || array[x] === 'i' || array[x] === 'o' || array[x] === 'u')
                      {
                        newarray.push(array[x].charAt(0).toLowerCase(array[x]))
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        newarray.push(array[x].charAt(0).toUpperCase(array[x]))
                      }
                    }
                    var pieces = newarray.join(' ');
                    tier.push(pieces.join(""))
             }


      if (font.constructor !== Array)
      {
        switch (font)
          {
            case 'camel':
            camel()
            return rez.join('')
            break

            case 'pascal':
            pascal()
            return rez.join('')
            break

            case 'snake':
            snake()
            return rez.join('')
            break

            case 'kebab':
            kebab()
            return rez.join('')
            break

            case 'title':
            title()
            return rez.join()
            break

            case 'vowel':
            vowel()
            return tier.join("")
            break

            case 'consonant':
            consonant()
            return tier.join("")
            break
          }
      }

      // **************************************TIER 2 AND 3 FONTS ********************************

      else if (font.constructor === Array)
      {
        switch (font)
        {
          // How do I join cases togather and combine my functions when multiple styles are needed?
        }
      }


      }
```

Basically I need to figure out how to apply the correct fonts when 2 styles/fonts are asked for. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Call multiple functions on same input

```
var functions = {
    pascal: (input) ->
       ...
    uppercase: (input) ->
       ...
}

if (typeof font !== 'array') {
    font = [font]
}

$.each(
    font,
    (fontType) ->
        input = functions[fontType]();
);
```

---

*Side note*:

All your functions basically do the same, so font should only define if it needs to keep letters case and separator (mind edge cases, like camelCase)

Comment: I’m just saying that `->`, `typeof` `"array"`, and the use of `$` without [tag:jquery] being tagged would all be incorrect, if this was JavaScript. If this is pseudo code, it’d be better to clearly state that in the answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: Can you please provide answer?